# Sharing data between classes when only knowing the interface they implement

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, interface, share

I am writing an application that will export a bunch of data from a database into files with specific file structures. There is only one 'type' of export defined so far but there will be more so I want to make it easy for new 'types' to be plugged in.
I have defined the following interface that all export 'types' must implement:

```
public interface IExportService
{
    ExportType ExportType { get; set; }
    Task DoExport(Store store);
}
```

The `ExportType` is an enum and the `Store` object is a customer ( rather than a data store of some kind ).

So far there is only one class that implements this interface : `RetailExportService`.

```
public class RetailExportService : IExportService
{
    public ExportType Type
    {
        get { return ExportType.Retail; }
    }

    public async Task DoExport(Store store)
    {
        List<IRetailExport> retailExports = GetRetailExportFiles();

        foreach (var retailExport in retailExports)
        {
            await retailExport.Export(store);
        }
    }

    private List<IRetailExport> GetRetailExportFiles()
    {
        return (from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                where t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IRetailExport))
                select Activator.CreateInstance(t) as IRetailExport).ToList();
    }

}
```

This class loops through all `IRetailExport` interfaces in the assembly and calls it's `Export` method. The actual querying of data and creation of files is done in the `Export` method.

```
public interface IRetailExport
{
    String FileName { get; }
    Task Export(Store store);
}
```

So, if a new file must be created I can just create a new class that implements `IRetailExport` and this will automatically be called by the application.

The problem I have is that I have 13 classes that implement `IRetailExport` and 5 of these classes require the same data. At the moment I am querying the database in each of the classes but this is a bad idea and slows down the application.

The only way I can think of doing this is to define an interface like so:

```
public interface IDataRequired<T> where T: class
{
    IEnumerable<T> Data { get; set; }
}
```

and have the classes the require the same data implement this class. In the `DoExport()` method I can then check if this class implements IDataRequired - if so, populate the Data property:

```
public async Task DoExport(Store store)
{
    List<IRetailExport> retailExports = GetRetailExportFiles();
    List<ExpRmProductIndex> requiredData = await GetIndexedProductList(store.Id);

    foreach (var retailExport in retailExports)
    {
        if (retailExport is IDataRequired<ExpRmProductIndex>)
            (retailExport as IDataRequired<ExpRmProductIndex>).Data = requiredData;

        await retailExport.Export(store);
    }
}
```

However, I don't think this is a very elegant solution so I was hoping someone here could suggest a better way of approaching this ? Thanks !!

Comment: Why wouldn't you change the DoExport signature - add a parameter requiredData of IEnumerable type like 

Task DoExport(Store store, IEnumerable requiredData);

if the implemention doesn't need the required data, it will just ignore the parameter.

and in the foreach loop always pass requiredData.

Comment: Hi @ViktorArsanov, thanks for your comment. I suppose I thought changing a method signature in one class to make another class work was a bad idea - maybe I am over thinking it and it's actually okay to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Reading from or writing to many files in parallel tasks is not a good idea, as this makes the disk head jump many times between the files what causes delays. (I assume that this happens if you have an `await` in a loop.)

Instead, process one file after the other in a strict sequential order and `await` once for the whole process to complete.